# How to count the occurrence of a value in each month

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a worksheet ('guests'), I have a list of guests and their admission and leave dates.

In a worksheet ('Report'), I want to know how many admitted and left in each month of the year and their names.

For example, in row 5 onwards:

- Cell 1: Name of guest
- Cell 2: Admission date
- Cell 3: Leave date

Comment: Your example is from the guests worksheet?  In the report, you say you want both a count and a list of names.  Your description leave a lot to the imagination.  It will be easier for people to answer if you include screenshots or a mock-up showing cell locations, what you want the output to look like, etc.  Please keep in mind that Super User isn't a coding service.  People will help you solve a problem, but it's expected that you show what you've attempted on your own.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Thank you, I will try, but I have a very limited script experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you want the "easiest" method of creating reports. There are many ways to achieve this, but the simplest for your desired outcome, I believe is this.

From the "guests" worksheet, tab over to "reports" worksheet and in the first cell enter the '=' sign, then click on the "guests" worksheet and click on the same cell from the "reports" sheet. Then click enter. You just entered a link and the same information will appear; a clone if you will. You want to clone all the data from the guests sheet to the report sheet. I assume you created the report sheet to keep the integrity of the quest worksheet. So I proceed in the fashion you have started with.

Then on the first row of the "reports sheet" you want to create a subtotal and a filter; the filter will be a custom filter based on date of arrival; "in" on the diagram below.

This is the manner I believe are trying to achieve your simple "report".

Here is a layout of the procedure in pictorial form:

[image]

- However if I was to create a report such as this I would import the sheet into an Access Database as a table, then create a report based on queries that are based on the table being imported; for a nice report. That's above the scope of your question and so would writing "script". Script being, a Visual Basic program writing project.

Comment: Omg, Excel is scaring me...

Comment: Thank you ejbytes very much for your reply. I will try it, I am sure this is what I need.